# Как получить результат асинхронной функции (Python aiosqlite)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Как можно получить результат `result` работы асинхронной функции (в переменную его запихнуть, переиспользовать и т.д., как в обычной функции `x = func(param)`?

Для примера - запрос к БД с помощью `aiosqlite`.

```
import aiosqlite
import asyncio

async def db_select(path, expression):
    async with aiosqlite.connect(path) as connection:
        cursor = await connection.cursor()
        await cursor.execute(expression)
        result = await cursor.fetchall()
        return result

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(db_select) #либо из asyncio.run, asyncio.gather И т.д.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два варианта, первый синхронизироваться:

```
result = loop.run_until_complete(db_select(param,param))
```

Второй передать результат в колбэк:

```
def callback(fut):
    result = fut.result()

asyncio.ensure_future(db_select(param,param)).add_done_callback(callback)
```

Comment: Спасибо, с коллбэком вариант пригодился)

Comment: С колбэком должен быть запущен луп