Что возвращает execute в aiosqlite
# Добавление задач в базу данных Sqlite.
async def add_task_to_database(task_name, user_id):
    connect = await aiosqlite.connect('users.db') # Название базы данных
    cursor = await connect.cursor()
    unic_id = await cursor.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM users_tasks') # SQL запрос
    unic_id = int(unic_id)
    await cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users_tasks (id, user_id, task) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', # SQL запрос
                         (unic_id, user_id, task_name))
    await connect.commit()
    await cursor.close()
    await connect.close()

При выполнении компилятор питона говорит, что возвращается "cursor", а мне нужно число.
В базе данных находится 1 элемент, т.е. по запросу SELECT count(*) FROM users_tasks возвращается 1, а в питон приходит непонятно что.

Ну хоть беглым взглядом пробегитесь по документации для приличия https://aiosqlite.omnilib.dev/en/stable/

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1105581/178576
